# if confirm show up when if condition parent is not met jquery

Tags: jquery, function, parameters, confirm

I have an image and a select option, I want the confirm window to show up when the image is clicked and the select option is not empty (another value than "none"). The image has an id which I get from the click function and the value of the select is on the same function, then I pass them as parameters to another function. I want the confirm to display a class and then send the id of the image to use it on an ajax function but it send the id anyways and it is not what i want

```
    $(childrenBoth, '#tratamientos').on('click', function () {
        let idImg = $(this).find('img').attr('id')
        let valorSelect = $("#tratSelect").val();
        seleccionar(idImg, valorSelect, id)
    } 

function seleccionar(valorSelect, id, idImg) {
    if (idImg !== undefined && valorSelect !== "none") {
        if (confirm('¿Seleccionar pieza Nro ' + id + '?')) {
            diente.push(idImg)
            sendId(diente)
        }
}
```

that is what I tried, could someone give me an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You do not nothing with the confirm

Answer (score 1):

You do nothing with the return value of the confirm.

```
if (confirm('¿Seleccionar pieza Nro ' + id + '?')) {
  diente.push(idImg)
  sendId(diente)
}
```

And your other issue

```
seleccionar(idImg, valorSelect) <-- TWO arguments
```

and

```
function seleccionar(valorSelect, id, idImg) <-- THREE and wrong order....
```

Learn to debug to see these things.

Comment: I fixed it and it show up anyway as if the previous if condition is not there